# Accessing files packaged into a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I created a jar file with a runnable compiled class and some template files (text). I now want to use the text files packaged into the jar for distribution in the application as `File` objects.

I tried to just use relative paths which did not work. **How do I get a `File` object pointing to a text file which is in the jar?**

Is there a way to do this so it will work both when running the unpackaged class files and from a jar with the same code, or will I need to use separate functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from inside jar you can use it like [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), or something similar.

from out side its not the file its jar so you will have to extract it in order to actually use inside file

Comment: So that’s for files. Theres no way to get a File object pointing to a directory, so one can get sub-files, right?

Comment: inside jar its not a file actually its a resource. you can tell me what you want to do exactly so that i can suggest you better way

Comment: I’m using FreeMarker library as a templating engine which I pass a templates-dir (`File`) as base-dir for the templates. Works well with a normal File object to the dir when running from IDE. No I’d like it to also run from a single Jar file. I managed to pack the files into the jar. Would I extract the files to a temp-dir, or is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know FreeMarker if you want to access file from out side from jar then extraction is the only way. otherwise if you are accessing file from other jar,war which has jar containing file in class path you can use above `getResourceAsStream()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the JAR within your application, then [`Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) will do.

Alternatively, if you're using Servlet, then `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(String)` will also do.

These 2 methods returns an `InputStream` (of your resource data) and not your `File` object as you rightfully want.