# Loading all files from a folder in a jar file

Tags: java, jar

**How can i load all files from a folder in a jar file?**

Untill now i was loading files from a folder like this `File[] files = new File("res/Models/" + dir).listFiles();` but it doesnt in a fat jar file (i get a `NullPointerException`).

*Note: The class that should load files and the files i want to load are in the same jar file. The line i wrote up there works when i run my program in eclipse, but when i expoort a jar file i get a NullPointerException for that line*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing files packaged into a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873716/accessing-files-packaged-into-a-jar-file?rq=1)

Comment: @Baz i think you should read my question and the question you linked again :)

Comment: I did, but I don't see the difference. Maybe you can explain...

Comment: I want to load all files from a folder!

Comment: As explained in the link Baz gave, you will need to extract the contents of the file first.

Comment: @Code-Guru Thank you. Maybe now it's more obvious, why this is a duplicate...

Comment: Do you see any difference between a FILE and ALL FILES IN A FOLDER?

Comment: @Chorche Yes. However, inside of a jar file there is no such thing as a "file" or a "folder". In order to reconstruct these things, you need to extract the contents of the Jar file.

Comment: *"How can i load all files from a folder in a jar file?"*  Using 'Fat Jar' is not usually the best way to implement things.  It is better to just add the dependent Jars to the run-time class-path of the application.  But the fact you are trying to find a list of those Jars is itself indicating you are very confused.  What user feature are you trying to implement through all this?  E.G. 'Can extend program using plug-ins!', or (what?)..

Comment: If you don't really have to get the actual files and it is sufficient with an `InputStream` then you can take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015747/get-all-images-within-directory-within-jar-file/12016222#12016222

Answer (score 2):

A jar file is a zip file, so you can read its contents using a ZipInputStream like this:

```
  ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
  ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
  ZipEntry entry = null;
  List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
  while ((entry = stream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    // this will get you the contents of the file
    InputStream inputStream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
    // this add the file path to the list
    filePaths.add(entry.getName());
  }
```

You can also do the follo

Comment: Can the "file" in this line `ZipInputStream stream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));` be a directory?

Comment: No, but you can have another method that recursively goes through the directory and if it finds a .zip file it calls the code I gave you, otherwise it does whatever you want it to do.

Comment: so i have to place my files into a zip archive? I think you dont understand what my question is. The class that should load files and the files i want to load are in the same folder. The line i wrote in my question works when i run my program in eclipse, but when i expoort a jar file i get a NullPointerException for that line. You should see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116151/fat-jar-instantly-closes/12116376

Comment: In this case, I think nobody understood what you asked. You should take your time to write questions that others can understand.

Comment: Oops, i ment that the class that should load files and the files i want to load are in the same jar file

Comment: I edited my answer. It shows you now how to read the contents of the files inside the jar/zip file. You will have to loop through the jar file and if the file path matches to what you are looking for, read its contents.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15787/discussion-between-chorche-and-dan)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how a `File` object works.

First, say we have the following code in a file named FileTest.java:

```
public class FileTest {
    public static void main() {
        File[] files = new File("temp").listFiles();

        for (File f : files) System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
}
```

When we compile this, javac creates a file named FileTest.class. (Even Eclipse will do this; it just places the .class files in a separate folder from the .java files.) Now when we run this program, it will look for a folder named "temp" located in the same folder as the FileTest.class file.

Now suppose that we create a JAR file named filetest.jar and add FileTest.class to it. Now if we run the program from the JAR file, it will look for a folder named "temp" located in the same folder as the **filetest.jar** file. In other words, `File` **only** looks for files and folders in the file system on your hard drive. It knows **absolutely nothing** about the contents of any files, **including filetest.jar**.

In order to read the contents of a JAR file, you **must** find a different solution. To start, you need to understand that inside a JAR file there is no such thing as "files" and "folders". A JAR file is simply a ZIP file with a few extra features. With the information you have given here so far, I believe that to solve your problem you will need to use [java.util.zip.ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html). I suggest you start by googling for a tutorial or browing the API doc which I have linked here.